# ffmpeg If input file not available means, Need skip options

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing video from n number of non-sequential images.  So I am using below command to create video from ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -r 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i "D:\filelist.txt" -c:v libx264 -vf "setpts=1*PTS" d:\out.mp4 -hide_banner
```

filelist.txt file contains below entries:

```
file '\1\1562776864008\1562776864.jpg'
file '\1\1562776864008\1562776865.jpg'
file '\1\1562776864008\1562776866.jpg'
file '\1\1562776864008\1562776867.jpg'
```

Above command works.  If all the files available in directory.

If any one of the file is missing, I get below output and cannot continue to create video for remaining files:

```
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[concat @ 000002c6724eb5c0] Impossible to open '\1\1562776864008\1562776865.jpg'
D:filelist.txt: No such file or directory
```

My requirement is to create video from images.  It may be some images missing in directory.  When image not available means need to continue video creation for remaining images.

Comment: Why does your filelist contain missing entries in the first place?

Comment: I have n number of files in a directory. Instead of iterating one by one I am just putting file list  by program(1562776864.jpg,1562776865.jpg,1562776866.jpg...for every second) like this.So it may be directory does not contains file for particular second.

Comment: So the files are being generated continuously by some other script? Perhaps you need to explain more about the overall situation. ffmpeg can't continue if a file is missing.

Comment: I want to monitor my desktop. So I created a script to take screenshot on every second on my desktop. After that need to convert those frames into a video. For converting frames into the video I am using ffmpeg.If any other tools available to achive my scenario please suggest me!!!

Comment: Why is a file missing if you create one every second? Or why do you put missing files into the filelist? Either way, you can create the file list *just* before you start the conversion. Just make sure to not put files in there that don't exist… or write a batch script that removes nonexisting files from the list.

Comment: File may be missing when there is any delay in my process. The only solution is cannot continue when a file is missing in file list for ffmpeg. So I need to give only existing files in filelist. Am i correct?If you know some other tools to achive my scenario please suggest!!!!

Comment: Yes, only put the files in there that are *actually* created. You don't need any other tools. Just fix the way you create the file. Don't write any file name in there that does not exist. (How are you creating the file? Maybe you can [edit] your question and explain better…)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for updating me with small span of time.You saved my time.Do you know any other tools to skip missing files when creating video from images?

Comment: Please note that when you ask about "tools that skip missing files", that will not really get you a solution, since you are then only asking about an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your list should not include any missing files, so either a) make sure that you don't write a non-existing file into that list, or b) clean the list before calling ffmpeg.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will update only existing files in filelist. Also i need one more solution  ffmpeg exe file size has 62MB. So when i bundle this into my project it increases size of my exe file.So can i minimize this size i need only one feature (create video from frames)?

Comment: You can compile ffmpeg with fewer tools, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide – but that would be too much to put into a comment. Note that if you bundle ffmpeg in your .exe, you have to respect its license: https://ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Comment: @BalakumarS You will have to compile it yourself. It is not a trivial task because it is easy to forget a component, and in addition compiling on Windows is not fun. Some examples: [How to compile ffmpeg to get only mp3 and mp4 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750953/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-to-get-only-mp3-and-mp4-support), [Best config for ffmpeg to convert MP3 file only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973461/best-config-for-ffmpeg-to-convert-mp3-file-only), [how do i modify this ffmpeg build script for minimal binary size?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912864/1109017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg has no option to skip missing files. Better solutions would be:

1. Do not write nonexisting files into your `.txt` file
2. Create a script that iterates through the `.txt` file and removes every line that refers to a nonexisting file

That way, ffmpeg will be able to correct open every specified input file.